# Is the image of a map of free modules flat?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules, flatness

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $\alpha:F_1\to F_2$ a map of free modules.

**Question:** is the image $\text{im}\alpha$ flat?

I've looked at the standard references, e.g. Stacks Project, and can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ideal $I=(x)/(x^2)$ in $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)=R$.

It is the image of the homomorphism $R\to R$ given by multiplication by $x$.

Now if $R$ is a commutative local ring, and we know that a finitely generated flat module over such a ring is free.  But that means $I$ cannot be flat: it is not free because it is annihilated by $x$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it's still true for the coimage, if you assume that the ring is reduced?

Comment: I don't know offhand, no.